# Activiti: Does Intermediate Timer Event fire if process ends before deadline?

Tags: business-process-management, bpmn, activiti

I am learning about activiti.  I have a parallel gateway with two branches.  One branch flows to a sequence of user tasks.  The other flows to an intermediate timer event that will fire in 15 days if the sequence isn't completed.

My question is if the sequence completes and the process ends, will the intermediate timer event disappear?  Or will it still fire in 15 days?

Note: I'm not using a boundary timer event because there are more than one task involved in the sequence.

Here's a crude diagram of what I'm doing.  The timer event executes something if the "user upload" and "manager review" process isn't completed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm currently learning the Activiti framework too so may be my response isn't the right one...

I think that, if your workflow reach the end point, the execution / workflow instance is terminated. So, the timer will not exists anymore.

May be you can test that by setting a 2 minutes timer and terminating your workflow process.

Comment: You are correct, intermediate timers are terminated on processing of the end event. Start timer events persist (as you would expect).

Answer (score 0):

the end event consumes the token of the branch.
to finish the process you have to consume **all** the tokens.

theoretically the process is not finished because you still have a token in the timer branch.

there are many design solution for doing what you do.